# List sorting WITH repetitions and LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, list, unity-game-engine

I tried to find something similar here but it looks like is not there...

I have the following piece of code that created a list with several elements. One of the elements is a "value" that I would like to sort the list by:

```
public int value;
public GameObject orbMesh;
public GameObject valueText;
public bool touchEnabled; 
public GameObject theOrbMesh;
public GameObject theValueText;   

List<Orb> myDeck = new List<Orb> ();

public Orb (int Value, GameObject OrbMesh, GameObject ValueText, bool TouchEnabled)
{
    value = Value;
    orbMesh = OrbMesh;
    valueText = ValueText;
    touchEnabled = TouchEnabled;
}

for (int z = 0; z < 4; z++)
{   
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
        myDeck.Add (new Orb (x + 1, Instantiate (theOrbMesh, new Vector3 (-3.6f + (x * 0.8f), -0.68f, z * 0.8f), Quaternion.identity), Instantiate (theValueText, new Vector3 (-3.6f + (x * 0.8f), -1f, z * 0.8f), Quaternion.identity), true));
    }
}
```

After this... I would like to sort myDeck by the "value" so I used this:

```
myDeck.OrderBy (w => w.value).ToList();
```

But it seems to be working only if there are no repetitions... unfortunately, I need it with repetitions on "value"...

Can you please help me with that? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: What do you mean "if there are no repetitions"? OrderBy doesn't care about repetitions. Also why are you using `ThenBy`? You already asked for sorting using that value. That's at best a noop, worst case it will simply iterate over the existing data

Comment: Your `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` sort by the same field, what do you expect it to do? Maybe you want `...ThenBy(w => w.valueText)`. But then `GameObject` need to implement `IComparable` or you have to select a property of this class(which you haven't shown), f.e.: `..ThenBy(w => w.valueText.Text)`

Comment: Make a Public Class `Orb` then in the class `public xValue {get; set; }`

Comment: Sorry, the ThenBy was some testing I was trying... my fault... I'm quite newbie on this :( I will edit the first post now.

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of code on one line. It'd be so much nicer for the next person to read / debug if you broke it into a few variables

Answer (score 2):

Ok, got it... I'm stupid...

```
myDeck.OrderBy (w => w.value).ToList();
```

should be:

```
myDeck = myDeck.OrderBy (w => w.value).ToList();
```

Seems like at some point I made a change and it was not sorting at all... with or with our repetitions... so... again... I'm stupid :(